# Configure Eclipse and PyDev for PyQt5 QtWebEngineWidgets?

Tags: python, eclipse, pyqt5, pydev

How do I configure Eclipse (with PyDev installed) so that my code can call QtWebEngineWidgets?

My Qt app works fine from the command line.  When I run the code in Eclipse, however, execution stops when it reaches

```
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import (
    QWebEngineView,
    QWebEngineSettings,
    )
```

with the error statement

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'
```

PyQt5 with QtWebEngineWidgets is installed on my system. Since the code runs fine from the command line, I think that I haven't configured Eclipse properly. What should I do?  Eclipse seems to find PyQt5, but it doesn't find the QtWebEngineWidgets module.

I've tried adding locations to the PYTHONPATH through Eclipse (Project > Properties > PyDev-PYTHONPATH), without success. I must not be including the right locations.  [image]

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.1, Eclipse 2018-09, PyQt5 5.11.2, Python 3.6.

Comment: I have not used pydev for some time but I have a query. Why do you have 2 pythons: python 3.6 and python 3.7? Do not you think that maybe you are using python 3.7 ?, verify that python is using in your script through: `import sys` `print(sys.version)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's running in the command line but not inside of PyDev, your problem should be some misconfiguration in the PYTHONPATH/env vars, so, you should compare those and fix the configuration in PyDev.

You can check:

http://www.pydev.org/faq.html#MyProgramDoesNotWorkInPyDev

For instructions on how to do that.

-- as a note, your libs really seem weird (it's mixing Python 3.6 and Python 3.7). Also, if you have `PyQt5` in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5`, only the parent directory (`/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`) should be in the `PYTHONPATH` (i.e.: remove `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5` from there).

Comment: Thank you so much, Fabio. Your guidance helped me match my PyDev PYTHONPATH configuration to mirror that of my command line. It worked!